# AngularJS Material - No data in select drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to populate a drop down in Material (AngularJS) but I do not receive any data in my dropdown on click of the dropdown.  I have checked the api and get data back.

However, in browser I do not see any data in my users scope property.  What am I doing wrong?

**API Snippet (Two Entries Shown)**

```
[{
        "userid": "2",
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "phone": "123-456-7890",
        "extension": "1234",
        "firstname": "fname",
        "lastname": "lname",
        "name": "lname, fname"
    },
    {
        "userid": "3",
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "phone": "123-456-7890",
        "extension": "1234",
        "firstname": "fname",
        "lastname": "lname",
        "name": "lname, fname"
    }]
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('Home', []);
angular.module('Action', ['datatables', 'datatables.scroller', 'ngResource']);          
angular.module('Risk',   ['datatables', 'datatables.scroller', 'ngResource']);          

var app = angular.module('Main', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'datatables', 'ngResource', 'ngMaterial', 'Home', 'Action', 'Risk']);

app.controller('MainController', ['DTOptionsBuilder']);

app.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider);
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('Action').config([
  '$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  }]).controller('CreateActionController', ['$http', '$resource', '$scope', '$state', '$timeout', function($http, $scope){

        $scope.users = null;
        $scope.user = null;

        $scope.initUsers = function(){
          $scope.users = $http.get('api/users').then(function(result){
            return result.data;
          });  
        }


        this.minDate = new Date();
        this.myDate = new Date();
        this.isOpen = false;

}]);
```

**Template**

```
<md-content ng-controller="CreateActionController as ctrl" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="" ng-app="Action">
<div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="ctrl.user" md-on-open="initUsers()" style="min-width: 200px;">
      <md-option ng-model="ctrl.user" ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">{{user.name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
    </div>
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <h6>Opening the calendar when the input is focused</h6>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-min-date="ctrl.minDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
</md-content>
```

**index.html**
**In Header**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
```

**Right before closing body tag**

```
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/jquery-slim-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angular-material-1.1.12/angular-material.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/popper-1.12.9/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/bootstrap-4.0.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/jquery-datatables-1.10.19/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
       <script src="/app/js/datatables-fixedheader-3.1.5/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angular-datatables-0.6.2/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angular-datatables-0.6.2/plugins/fixedheader/angular-datatables.fixedheader.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angular-datatables-0.6.2/plugins/scroller/angular-datatables.scroller.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/statehelper.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/angularjs-1.6.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/js/ocLazyLoad/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
       <script src="/app/route-config.js"></script> 
       <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to **return** `$http.get` from `$scope.init` function.

```
$scope.init = function()
{
      return $http.get('api/users').then(function(response){
           $scope.users = response.data;
           return response.data;
      });  
}
```

Controller

```
angular.module('Action').config([
  '$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  }]).controller('CreateActionController', ['$http', '$resource', '$scope', '$state', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $resource, $scope, $state, $q, $timeout){


        $scope.users = {};
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.usr = {};



    $scope.init = function()
    {
          return $http.get('api/users').then(function(response){
              $scope.users = response.data;
              return response.data;
          });  
    }   


        this.minDate = new Date();
        this.myDate = new Date();
        this.isOpen = false;

}]);
```

Template

```
<md-content ng-controller="CreateActionController" ng-init="init()" ng-app="Action" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="">
<div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="users"  style="min-width: 200px;"/>
        <md-option ng-model="user" ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users track by user.userid">{{user.name}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <h6>Opening the calendar when the input is focused</h6>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-min-date="minDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two functions were needed,  init and populateUserList (which returns a timeout).  My drop down now has data onclick with init called to fetch data before click.

**Template (removed 'as ctrl' and all ctrl. in front of scope vars in template)**

```
<md-content ng-controller="CreateActionController" ng-init="init()" ng-app="Action" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="">
<div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="users" md-on-open="populateUserList()" style="min-width: 200px;"/>
       <md-option ng-model="user" ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users track by user.userid">{{user.name}}</md-option> <!-- track by user.userid is needed -->
    </md-select>
    </div>
    <div flex-gt-xs>
      <h6>Opening the calendar when the input is focused</h6>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-min-date="minDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
</md-content>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('Action').config([
  '$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  }]).controller('CreateActionController', ['$http', '$resource', '$scope', '$state', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $resource, $scope, $state, $q, $timeout){


        $scope.users = {};
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.usr = {};

        function getUsers()
        {
          return $http.get('api/users').then(function(response){
                return response.data;
          });  
        } 

        $scope.init = function()
        {
          getUsers().then(function(data){
                $scope.usr = data;  
          });    
        }

        $scope.populateUserList = function(){
            return $timeout(function() {
             $scope.users = $scope.usr;
            }, 0);
        }

        this.minDate = new Date();
        this.myDate = new Date();
        this.isOpen = false;

}]);
```

Comment: I do not know how to not populate user list without a timeout of 0 as seen in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initUsers` function:

```
$scope.initUsers = function() {
    $http.get('api/users').then(function(result) {
        $scope.users = result.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: For some reason I started off with this approach,  but I discovered I had to return from the anonymous function inside then, then return the $http.get from my main fnction.

Comment: I tried however to paste the code, it produces an empty select box.

Comment: Attempted modification still gives an empty dropdown.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not in a position to test this out.  The other thing that comes to mind is that a `$scope.digest()` is required, but I thought that $http would trigger that automatically.

Comment: No worries,  I already produced a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55836053/1691103

Comment: I believe my reasoning behind the answer was in discovering previously that $http.get returns a promise.  So return that promise from with a parent function and then call parent like so.  parent().then(function(result){})l

Comment: I tested the code I wrote in my answer, and all seems to be working.  It should be as simple as this.

Comment: Modifying init to return http get and assign to scope.users to response.daa, then returning response.data from the response handler produced a more compact code.